# Force multipeer connection to close

Tags: ios, p2p, multipeer-connectivity

Is there a way to end a (ios 7) multipeer connection? As in, not completely disconnect the local peer but instead just disable the connection with a specific peer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only peer that you can disconnect from an `MCSession` is yourself, so you'd need to create a new session for each peer you connect to. You can keep those sessions in a dictionary with the connected peer's `displayName` property as a key, and when you want to disconnect a given peer, grab the relevant `MCSession` and send that session a `disconnect` message.